# Animation width to actual width in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, animation

How can I animate the width of an element from 0 to its actual width in WPF?

I tried this:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3" To="{Binding ElementName=MyElement, Path=ActualWidth}" From="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Storyboard.TargetName="MyElement" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

If I change the binding to a hard coded value, like `100`, then the width is properly animated, except that I want to bind to the actual width of the element.

If it matters, `MyElement` is a border, and I'm animating a tab item.

For the record, this does not work either:

```
To="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm sure this is wrong for SO many reasons and please feel free to tell me how many WPF laws I've violated but.. I solved the same problem by creating my own BindableDoubleAnimation.

```
public class BindableDoubleAnimation : DoubleAnimationBase
{
    DoubleAnimation internalAnimation;

    public DoubleAnimation InternalAnimation { get { return internalAnimation; } }

    public double To
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ToProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ToProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dependency backing property for the <see cref="To"/> property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("To", typeof(double), typeof(BindableDoubleAnimation), new UIPropertyMetadata(0d, new PropertyChangedCallback((s, e) =>
            {
                BindableDoubleAnimation sender = (BindableDoubleAnimation)s;
                sender.internalAnimation.To = (double)e.NewValue;
            })));


    public double From
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(FromProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FromProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dependency backing property for the <see cref="From"/> property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FromProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("From", typeof(double), typeof(BindableDoubleAnimation), new UIPropertyMetadata(0d, new PropertyChangedCallback((s, e) =>
        {
            BindableDoubleAnimation sender = (BindableDoubleAnimation)s;
            sender.internalAnimation.From = (double)e.NewValue;
        })));


    public BindableDoubleAnimation()
    {
        internalAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    }

    protected override double GetCurrentValueCore(double defaultOriginValue, double defaultDestinationValue, AnimationClock animationClock)
    {
        return internalAnimation.GetCurrentValue(defaultOriginValue, defaultDestinationValue, animationClock);
    }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return internalAnimation.Clone();;
    }
}
```

I'm now free to use bindings for the To From properties.

```
<local:BindableDoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="0" To="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
```

Comment: Has anybody gotten this to work for `BindableDoubleAnimation`s that are inside of a `Storyboard` that is in a `VisualState` of a `ControlTemplate`? For cases where I have just a single `BindableDoubleAnimation` in the `VisualState` and I hardcode the "To" value (to say something like "100"), nothing gets animated, and neither `GetCurrentValueCore` nor `CreateInstanceCore` are getting called.  For cases where I use data binding on the "To" property the binding always fails, always outputting the error "Cannot find source for binding...". Even when I try everything from above verbatim, it fails.

Comment: ... I'd love to get this to work - it seems like it could be a great solution!

Answer (score 2):

That bindings cannot be used in animations is a common problem.

One workaround would be that you use a helper object which has `SourceValue` & `TargetValue` (which you can bind to whatever you want, including `ActualWidth`) a `CurrentValue` (which returns the animated value) and a `Progress` which can be animated from 0.0 to 100.0. When the progress is changed you just need to calculate the `CurrentValue` to which you then can bind the `Width` of your object. It is not pretty but should work.

Comment: I am not clear on this answer. Could you provide a code sample? Are you describing something similar to @Andy's solution?

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens: Andy's answer always modifies the animation by creating a bindable layer on top of it. What i suggest is different, i suggest an intermediary object that always uses the same animation that animates its `Progress` property from `0` to `100` (thus the animation does not change), this object provides the animation value via a `CurrentValue` property that returns the value calculated from its `SourceValue`, `TargetValue` and `Progress`.