# Trouble binding storyboard values to viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, binding

I'm having trouble getting a storyboard value to bind to my viewmodel.  I've tried many varieties of binding xaml, with no luck. The high level goal is to be able for the ViewModel to change the start and end of an animation's trajectory - seems like a common requirement, but haven't been able to find any examples of it.  Many people say "In MVVM you should never try to access the storyboard from the ViewModel" which seems like horeshit if you need to change the start and end points of the animation on the fly.  In any case, I've shown my first, naive example here:

```
<UserControl 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FishTank" x:Class="FishTank.FishTankControlView" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100" >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames x:Name="xTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-155"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4.5" Value="521"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames x:Name="yTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding YPos1}"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4.5" Value="{Binding YPos2}"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:FishTankControlViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{DynamicResource Storyboard1}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>

<Grid Background="Transparent">
    <Image x:Name="image" Width="100" Height="100" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Fish orange_right.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

I want to have Ypos1 and Ypos2 bound to the start and end points of the Y transformation.  I've tried various variations using RelativeSource and FindAncestor, but it's all pretty much over my head.  I would like a solution that allows me to stick with the 3.5 framework if possible.

I tried changing the "StaticResource Storyboard1" to "DynamicResource Storyboard1" with no luck.

Note - As a sanity check, I confirmed I am able to bind normal controls like buttons and textblocks to these two properties, Ypos1 and Ypos2, so I'm pretty sure the basic plumbing is working...

Thanks much,
Randy

Comment: any binding errors in output or immediate window

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind those because they need to be freezable, pretty sure the framework told you so as well.

If anything you can completely recreate or modify the animation with new values, using a `ValueConverter` or a subclass that encapsulates the animation being modified.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how to implement either of these suggestions. I've done a valueconverter before but it seems like first I need to get the bind working, then the valueconverter just modifies it before binding, right?  Stepping back a bit, perhaps you can recommend a different approach to do dynamic animations?  I can't figure out how to get ahold of the storyboard object in the viewmodel, for example.

Comment: @RandyGamage: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994716/animation-width-to-actual-width-in-wpf/10995041) might illustrate the encapsulation approach. For the `ValueConverter` approach you would put a [`MutliBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) on the `BeginStoryboard.Storyboard` property, the bindings would be to the start and end values, the converter then will be called every time one of those changes. Inside the converter you will have to construct and return the whole storyboard with the passed in current values.

Comment: Thanks, that question does provide a workaround for this issue, it's just surprising how complicated it is and that there isn't a way to directly bind to a storyboard.  I think my best route is to forget about storyboards, just use a timer to update the location of the image and be done with it.  Too bad the WPF animation is so difficult to change dynamically.